# How to correctly setup a conditional expression (if) in a React render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I want to be able to rendering a certain section of HTML if the condition is true.  I am curious about the correct way to setup a conditional if expression within a `react` render().

I looked it up online and found one way to do this with a inline expression to check if the value is true, if so then it will render the remaining element.

I also setup another way to create variables for the html to be rendered.

**Question:**

I was unable to wrap both `td` tags as one for the condition.  It looks like this needs to be done per `td` tag.

Is there a way to do this around both tags or does it require setting up another element around them?

I thought this could also be setup using a `=>` function possibly.

Code for inline render() expression:

```
render() {

    // get the data from the JSON entity for each attribute
    var tdsForObject = this.props.jsonAttributes.map(jsonAttribute =>
        <td>{this.props.object.entity[jsonAttribute]}</td>
    );

    return (
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          {tdsForObject}
          {this.props.objectTypeEditable &&
            <td>
              <UpdateDialog object={this.props.object}
                      objectName={this.props.objectName}
                      attributes={this.props.attributes}
                      onUpdate={this.props.onUpdate}/>
            </td>
          }
          {this.props.objectTypeEditable &&
              <td>
              <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
            </td>
          }
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    )
  }
```

Code to create buttons outside of render()

```
render() {

    // get the data from the JSON entity for each attribute
    var tdsForObject = this.props.jsonAttributes.map(jsonAttribute =>
        <td>{this.props.object.entity[jsonAttribute]}</td>
    );

    var updateButton;
    var deleteButton;

    // if the object can be edited create the update and delete buttons
    if (this.props.objectTypeEditable) {
      updateButton = (
        <td>
          <UpdateDialog object={this.props.object}
                  objectName={this.props.objectName}
                  attributes={this.props.attributes}
                  onUpdate={this.props.onUpdate}/>
        </td>
      );

      deleteButton = (
        <td>
          <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
        </td>
      );
    }

    return (
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          {tdsForObject}
          {updateButton}
          {deleteButton}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX doesn't allow you to return 2 side by side elements. It can only return 1 element. So yeah you can either wrap those 2 inside a single element and use the same verification as you do now.

```
{this.props.objectTypeEditable &&
    <div class="wrapper">
        <td>
            [...]
        </td>
        <td>
            [...]
        </td>
    </div>
}
```

You can also use [inline self invoked function](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html) and return an array of JSX elements. *(the render methods will automatically loop through them and render them)*.  Here I use ES6 arrow function to bind directly the `this` reference but it is probably doable with a normal function and binding it by hand like this `.bind(this)`

```
{(() => {
    let elements = [];
    if(this.props.objectTypeEditable) {
        // push td elements in array
    }
    return elements;
})()}
```

Comment: @Raphael_Parent Yes I did see the ES6 arrow function like you showed on React's website.  I tried this method and it works as well.   I am new to react and out of all the 3 different types discussed above I find the one setting up the td's in a variable the easiest to read.  I am new to react though so I am not sure.  Would this be thought of as a correct solution or should this try to be pushed into the return body?  I find it a lot easier to read setup with the if statement and variable declaration prior to the return as shown in the second code section above.

Comment: @ALM It's a correct solution for your question. You asked `Is there a way to do this around both tags or does it require setting up another element around them?` and I answered it :). There's a way, it works, it's a bit less readable. It's up to you! I wouldn't mind seeing one or the other.

Comment: @Raphael_Parent I understand your answer's the question, I can mark it correct.  I wanted to know though are any of these 3 solutions better than another?  My preferred solution is the one I provided in my second code example and I just want to make sure that its ok within a way to do react as I am new to it.

Thanks

Comment: @ALM Personally if there's a lot of verification and all i like to do it outside the return like you did, but for your case I'd stick with your first choice.

Comment: You can in fact render side by side elements, just put them in an array with keys, `[<td key="first" />, <td key="second" />]`, you don't need the IIFE to do this.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) expression

> condition ? expr1 : expr2

```
render() {

    // get the data from the JSON entity for each attribute
    var tdsForObject = this.props.jsonAttributes.map(jsonAttribute =>
        <td>{this.props.object.entity[jsonAttribute]}</td>
    );

    return (
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          {tdsForObject}
          { this.props.objectTypeEditable
            ? <td>
                <UpdateDialog object={this.props.object}
                      objectName={this.props.objectName}
                      attributes={this.props.attributes}
                      onUpdate={this.props.onUpdate}/>
              </td>
            : null
          }
          { this.props.objectTypeEditable 
            ? <td>
                <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
              </td>
            : null
          }
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    )
  }
```

It is not possible to use more than one inline. React's documentation and examples use ternary operations and recommends it as the default pattern. If you prefer one method over the other thats fine, they are both valid, just stick to one for consistency's sake :)

Comment: Hi John.  I know how to add a second condition, I wanted to know if there is a way to have both TD's in the same conditional expression?  Also if one method is considered better than the other.

Comment: @ALM no it is not possible to do it inline. the answer I gave is the preferred pattern with react where you check for the same thing multiple times, but there must always be a high level single element that is returned so that JSX knows what its tree is. However it really just boils down to user preference. If you like one over the other they are both valid. so just make sure you are consistent with the implementation you use

Comment: So you should always provide both so that it can render one or the other?  Would it not default to empty since nothing was provided?  I'm just trying to see is there any difference to JSX between what you wrote and what I wrote?  They will both render the same I'm just not returning the null.

Comment: Implicit types are always better. returning exactly what you want. React may just put in an empty span somewhere if theres an extra space it reads or something. I always prefer to know what will be rendered all the time.